# What is the point of cell indexing in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, indexing, cell-array

The point of indexing is mainly to get the value. In MATLAB,
for a cell array, there is content indexing (`{}`), and thus cell indexing (`()`) is only for selecting a subset from the cell array, right?

Is there anything other advanced usage for it?  Like using it as
a pointer and pass it to a function?

Comment: If the answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates that you've found a solution and this is no longer an open question. If your question is not answered, please explain what’s missing.

Answer (score 4):

There is a heavily simplified answer. {}-indexing returns you the content, ()-indexing creates a subcell with the indexed elements. Let's take a simple example:

```
>> a=x(2)

a = 

    [2]

>> class(a)

ans =

cell

>> b=x{2}

b =

     2

>> class(b)

ans =

double
```

Now continue with non-scalar elements. For the ()-indexing everything behaves as expected, you receive a subcell with the elements:

```
>> a=x(2:3)

a = 

    [2]    [3]
```

The thing really special to Matlab is using {}-indexing with non-scalar indices. It returns a [Comma-Separated List](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/comma-separated-lists.html) with all the contents. Now what is happening here:

```
>> b=x{2:3}

b =

     2
```

The Comma-Separated List behaves similar to a function with two return arguments. You want only one value, only one value is assigned. The second value is lost. You can also use this to assign multiple elements to individual lists at once:

```
>> [a,b]=x{2:3} %old MATLAB versions require deal here

a =

     2


b =

     3
```

Now finally to a very powerful use case of comma separated lists. Assume you have some stupid function foo which requires many input arguments. In your code you could write something like:

```
foo(a,b,c,d,e,f)
```

Or, assuming you have all parameters stored in a cell:

```
foo(a{1},a{2},a{3},a{4},a{5},a{6})
```

Alternatively you can call the function using a comma separated list. Assuming a has 6 elements, this line is fully equivalent to the previous:

```
foo(a{:}) %The : is a short cut for 1:end, index the first to the last element
```

The same technique demonstrated here for input arguments can also be used for output arguments.

Regarding your final question about pointers. Matlab does not use pointers and it has no supplement for it (except `handle` in oop Matlab), but Matlab is very strong in optimizing the memory usage. Especially using [Copy-on-write](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write) makes it unnecessary to have pointers in most cases. You typically end up with functions like

```
M=myMatrixOperation(M,parameter,parameter2)
```

Where you input your data and return it.

Comment: so basically, what () can do, { } can do too, plus get the content, why do we need () then?

Comment: You can always replace `x(2:3)` with `{x{2:3}}`. Besides saving some chars, having ()-indexing for cells and matrices with the same behaviour simplifies functions which can process both.

Comment: Note that you can only replace `x(…)` indexing with `{x{…}}` if the result is a 1D cell array. For example, `x(:,1:3)` cannot be done in any other way. The two forms of indexing are different and you need both to use cell arrays properly.